# How to get Dimension of twodimensional Array

Tags: java

Programming Language is `Java`. 
I have a twodimensional `Array int[][] x = new int[n][m]`. 
In the following code i have only `x` and do not know `n` and `m`.
Is it possible to get Information about `n` and `m` only from `x`?

Answer (score 3):

The `length` attribute of an array gives its dimension.  To find the second dimension, you can get the dimension of one of the sub-arrays (assuming they are all the same).

Answer (score 0):

For n use:

```
x.length
```

For m use:

```
x[0].length
```